# How to find dimension of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$. Let $X$ be a subspace of  $L(V, W)$ given by $$X=\{S\in L(V,W)| U\subseteq null(S)\}.$$

How can I find the dimension of $X$ in terms of dimension of $V,W, U$

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is the space of linear maps $V/U\to W$.  Thus if $U,V,W$ have dimensions $u,v,w$ respectively, an element of $X$ is determined by taking a basis of $V/U$ and assigning a vector in $W$ to each element of the basis.  A basis of $V/U$ has $v-u$ elements, so:
$${\rm dim}(X)=(v-u)w.$$